# GWT and setting "file://" on HREFs

Tags: javascript, gwt

Greetings,

I'm using GWT and trying to set an href to a file uri (to a network share) and insert it into a cell of a FlexTable and can't seem to make it work.

I have inspected the dynamic anchor in chrome (inspector) and the format is correct but nothing happens when I click on it.

I have tried setting through an Anchor, HTML object, calling cell.setHTML directly and also tried setting it outside the flex table but all to no avail.

Note that I can create a simple HTML file that looks like:

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
  <a target="_blank" href="file://///server/share/myfile.txt">My File</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and have it work correctly across Chrome, IE, firefox when I load it on the address bar.

Any thoughts? TIA

Comment: Where are your pages running? Where is your test HTML that works running?

Comment: Everything is local on my machine.  I have access to the share and can type the file:// directly on the address bar and have it work.  I even tried doing a simple GWT project with just a simplepanel and still no joy.

Comment: Didn't you get the answer already on http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/e5addadc8ce88d15?

Comment: Not me but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

"For security purposes, Mozilla applications block links to local files (and directories) from remote files."[1](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work)